React Native animation delay
I have the following code:
  const ScrollScreen = () => {
    const scrollY = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;

    const paddingTop = scrollY.interpolate({
      inputRange: [200, 400],
      outputRange: [0, 100],
      extrapolate: "clamp",
    });
  
    return (
      <ScrollView
        stickyHeaderIndices={[3]}
      >
        <SomeOtherComponent1 />
        <SomeOtherComponent2 />
        <SomeOtherComponent3 />
        <Animated.View style={{ paddingTop }}>
          <Text>Some text </Text>
        </Animated.View>
      </ScrollView>
    );
  };

The idea is to gradually add a padding to the Text component as we scroll up, so that by the time the scroll is past 400px, it has a paddingTop of 100px and will never touch the top of the screen even when fixed via the stickyHeaderIndices property.
I noticed that this works great if we scroll up slowly, but if we do a quick swipe up, the Text component will go all the way to the top of the screen first, before dropping to the expected 100px.
I guess the interpolation doesn't seem to catch on quick enough, but is there any solution to fix this for quick scrolls?

Where is scrollY getting set?

@johnhaup Sorry I missed it, just updated the code.

Can you try something like that.


import React, { useRef } from 'react';
import { Animated, ScrollView, View, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

const MyScrollView = () => {
  const scrollY = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;

  const paddingTop = scrollY.interpolate({
    inputRange: [0, 50], // Adjust the input range as needed
    outputRange: [0, 20], // Adjust the output range as needed
    extrapolate: 'clamp',
  });

  return (
    <Animated.ScrollView
      onScroll={Animated.event(
        [{ nativeEvent: { contentOffset: { y: scrollY } } }],
        { useNativeDriver: false }
      )}
      scrollEventThrottle={16}
    >
      <Animated.View style={[styles.item, { paddingTop }]}>
        <Text>First Item</Text>
      </Animated.View>
      <View style={styles.item}>
        <Text>Second Item</Text>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.item}>
        <Text>Third Item</Text>
      </View>
      {/* Add more items as needed */}
    </Animated.ScrollView>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  item: {
    height: 100,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    borderBottomColor: '#ccc',
  },
});

export default MyScrollView;



